# Haskell - Find a path through declared graph Type

Tags: haskell

```
type Node = Integer
type Edge = (Integer, Integer)
type Graph = [Edge]
type Path = [Node]

g :: Graph
g = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)]
h :: Graph
h = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (3,2), (4,4)]
```

For an assignment, we are working with the defined types above and have to implement a few functions. Currently I'm trying to write a function called paths which will return a list of all possible cycle-free paths. So for example if I called `paths 1 4 g` the output would be `=> [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,4], [1,3,4]]`

I have an already written function for returning the adjacent nodes of a given node.

```
adjacent :: Node -> Graph -> [Node]
adjacent n gr = [ y | (x, y) <- gr, x == n]
```

I'm having trouble getting started. I believe I will need to use adjacent to get each of the adjacent nodes and then the adjacent nodes to those nodes until I finish my destination node. Just wondering if I'm on the right track or some helpful guidance, thanks!

*EDIT* So just wanted to post an update. Been searching around and found a way to build a list of all paths from a starting node...

```
allPaths :: Node -> Graph -> [Path]
allPaths startNode graph = map (startNode:) (go startNode)
  where
    go curNode =
      case [ snd node | node <- graph, fst node == curNode ] of
        [] -> [[]]
        nextNodes -> [ nextNode : path | nextNode <- nextNodes, path <- go nextNode ]
```

When adding in a end Node, is there a way to only return the paths that reach this end node?

Comment: That is the exhaustive search approach, but this will run exponential in the size of the graph. I propose that you take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm, but drop the minimality constraint.

Comment: To find all paths from start node to end node you have to look through all paths from start node anyway. So my approach would be to find all possible paths from start node (beware of cycles!) and filter out only ones containing the end node. You should look up the Depth-first search algorithm (DFS) because it is a recursive algorithm, so it would not be that hard to implement in Haskell